# Group columns into a row, ignoring nulls in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to join columns into a single row. Here's an example of my data:

```
 name |  x   |  y   | value
------+------+------+-------
  A   |  N   | null |   x
  A   | null |  M   |   y
  B   |  O   | null |   x
  B   | null |  P   |   y
```

I have the possibility instead to work with the following:

```
 name | value | data
------+-------+------
  A   |   x   |  N
  A   |   y   |  M
  B   |   x   |  O
  B   |   y   |  P
```

And this is what I'm trying to obtain:

```
 name |  x   |  y   
------+------+------
  A   |  N   |  M
  B   |  O   |  P
```

I have tried grouping, but since I can't do it by a single column, I couldn't manage to get it right.

Something else I have tried was joining the table to itself `n` times, where `n` = number of columns I wanted to get, but that was suboptimal, and took quite a bit of time to run.

I created the first example from a query because that was the closer I could manage to get from what I wanted, but I might have complicated things in doing so.

*Edit:* I'd like to point out that the columns `x` and `y` are `varchar`s, so I can't use `max` on them. I have corrected the sample data with a closer example to what I have. The column `value` is where I put the data (everything comes from an external table).

Comment: What if you have a third row for `name = 'A'` with a value for `x`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That is not possible in this instance, so it wouldn't be a problem!

Comment: "*I'd like to point out that the columns x and y are varchars, so I can't use max on them*" - of course you can. What makes you think you can't use `min()` on a varchar column?

Comment: This is now a **completely** different question then your original one.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Because they have characters, not integers. I might be wrong, but you can't do max on a value such as `'hello'`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yeah, I noticed I oversimplified so much I might have confused people. Sorry!

Comment: Of course you can use `max()` or `min()` on a varchar. You do expect to be able to use such a column in an `ORDER BY` do you? If you can sort by a value you obviously can determine the max and min value for that as well

Answer (score 0):

You should show what you tried.  This is a simple aggregation:

```
select name, max(x) as x, max(y) as y
from t
group by name;
```

Most likely, you generated this data using an aggregation query of some sort.  That query does not have the right `group by` keys and can probably be easily fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by name and then get the max value from each group, as in:

```
select
  name, max(x), max(y)
from t
group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a CTE and joining the table to itself to insert the y value onto the x value row gives you the list you are looking for.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT 
    table1.name,table1.x,table12.y
FROM table1
left join (select name,y from table1 where value = 'y') as table12 on table1.name = table12.name
WHERE value = 'x'
)
select * from CTE
```